# Simple question for Jaeger demo: what are the bare minimum working components

Tags: jaeger, hot-rod

I am trying out Jaeger on a Linux VM:
The all-in-one version works perfectly with Demo hotrod app.

However when starting up the jaeger collector and query separately (I used the binaries with  --span-storage.type=memory) it does not seem to work: No services show up in the UI, not even the jaeger-query service...

What is the bare minimum options to get Jaeger up and running without using the all-in-one version?

In more detail: I run
./example-hotrod --jaeger-ui http://hostname:16686/ all

And then the all-in-one binary and it works perfectly.

However when I try:

./jaeger-collector --span-storage.type=memory
./jaeger-query --span-storage.type=memory

or adding more options e.g:
./jaeger-collector --span-storage.type=memory --collector.zipkin.host-port=hostname:9411 --collector.otlp.http.host-port http://hostname:55681 --collector.zipkin.host-port=hostname:9411 --collector.otlp.http.host-port hostname:55681  --collector.grpc-server.host-port hostname:14250 --collector.otlp.enabled

Then nothing is visible in the services...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that two things were needed for it to work properly:

1. the Agent (although in documentation it states that it is deprecated and is not required)
2. --span-storage.type should not be memory. For some reason it does not work (I tried elasticsearch and it worked just fine)